# Python, Display openCv image in Tkinter in Label

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, tkinter

I'm trying display openCV image in Tkinter label. When I load image from file like:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage("asd.png")
```

everythink works fine. But when I change it, I get only empty, black image, anythink else. This is example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import cv2
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from skimage.color import rgb2gray


def make_label(master, x, y, w, h, img, *args, **kwargs):
   f = Frame(master, height = h, width = w)
   f.pack_propagate(0)
   f.place(x = x, y = y)
   label = Label(f, image = img, *args, **kwargs)
   label.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
   return label


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = tk.Tk()
   frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=600, background='white')
   frame.pack_propagate(0)
   frame.pack()
   image = rgb2gray(io.imread("asd.png"))

   image2 = Image.fromarray(image)
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
   make_label(root, 0, 0, 100, 100, img)
   root.mainloop()
```

Please, help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the greyscale values given by `rgb2gray(io.imread("asd.png"))` are between 0 and 1 while PIL expects values between 0 and 255, so the result of `Image.fromarray(image)` is a black square since all values are smaller than 1.

Therefore `image2 = Image.fromarray(image*255)` should give the expected image.